# The results are not displaying on the screen but im getting no console error

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to run a query against the database that returns the information I want. I now want to display it on the screen.

```
function display(parsed) {
article = document.getElementById("homeArticle");
item = '<p>Something should go here</p>';
for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
    var item = parsed[i];

    var name = item.P_NAME;
    var description = item.P_DESCRIPTION;
    var price = item.P_PRICE;
        // next I add to the string that we want to place on the page
    item += '<section id="homePageSection"> <p>Name:' + name + '</p><p>Description:' + description + '</p><p>Price:' + price + '</p></section>';
};
article.innerHTML = item;
}


function getItems() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.response)
        var parsed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        display(parsed.rows);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "displayData.php");
    xhr.send();
}

window.addEventListener("load", getItems);
```

However this does not display the results on the screen. I used console.log to see if it was the getItems function that was not working but this logs the information I want so I am getting the correct information I just need it to display on the screen but i don't know why it is not?

below is what is logged in the console.

```
{"rows":[{"P_ID":"1","P_NAME":"Iphone 6","P_DESCRIPTION":"the latest iphone","P_PRICE":"300"},{"P_ID":"2","P_NAME":"Ipad Mini","P_DESCRIPTION":"the latest and smallest ipad","P_PRICE":"199.99"},{"P_ID":"3","P_NAME":"MacBook Pro","P_DESCRIPTION":"the macbook pro","P_PRICE":"999"},{"P_ID":"4","P_NAME":"Ipad Cover","P_DESCRIPTION":"a cover for ipad","P_PRICE":"30"},{"P_ID":"8","P_NAME":"Iphone 5c","P_DESCRIPTION":"the iphone 5c","P_PRICE":"150"},{"P_ID":"9","P_NAME":"Windows 8 laptop","P_DESCRIPTION":"a laptop with windows 8","P_PRICE":"250"}]}
```

Comment: can you share the html fragment this uses?

Comment: `innerHtml !== innerHTML`, JS is case-sensitive. Fixing this would show you `undefined`s, you'll need also JLRishe's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing the raw response text to your function instead of the parsed object.

Should be this:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.response)
    var parsed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    display(parsed);   // <-----
};
```

There are also several issues in your `display` function:

```
                  // v----- this said parsed instead of results
function display(results) {
    article = document.getElementById("homeArticle");
    item = '<p>Something should go here</p>';
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var item = results[i];

        var name = item.P_NAME;
        var description = item.P_DESCRIPTION;
        var price = item.P_PRICE;
            // next I add to the string that we want to place on the page
        item += '<section id="homePageSection"> <p>Name:' + name + '</p><p>Description:' + description + '</p><p>Price:' + price + '</p></section>';
    }
    article.innerHTML = item;  // needs to be innerHTML
}
```

**Edit:** Your array is on a property called `rows`, so you either need to access this property when passing it into `display()`:

```
display(parsed.rows);
```

*Or* access it inside your `display()` function:

```
function display(response) {
    var results = response.rows;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Similarly, the parameter to `display` is called `parsed` and yet within the body of `display`, `parsed` is never used but a seemingly undefined variable `results` is.

Comment: yes sorry i have edited this and changed all of them to parsed but this is still not working, i will edit the code above to show I have acknowledge this error from me.

Comment: sorry yes, i have changed that now my bad!!

Comment: in the code above does `results.length` and `var item = results [ i ]` need to be `parsed.length` and so on?

Comment: @TomPhillippe Your code works now.  Are you sure the result is properly an array of objects?  http://jsfiddle.net/orxkxx23/1

Comment: @TomPhillippe I changed the function's parameter name to `results` because that made more sense than calling it `parsed`. So the code that I posted is internally consistent.

Comment: okay thanks guys, i understand this all and appreciate your help, however it still is not displaying the results?

Comment: yes from what i believe is a JSON Array ill post what i get in the console.log above as easier to format the code.

Comment: thats brilliant, thank you so much @JLRishe you have been so much help!